# Por ejemplo hola con punto es correcto o se escribe sin punto me refiero cuando va sola

Tags: gramática

Por ejemplo, en el chat le escribo a alguien y solo inicio la conversación con :
Hola.

Hola

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente cuando entablamos conversación en un chat con alguien, escribimos simplemente **Hola**, **hola**, sin punto, en todo caso una coma para continuar la conversación o en interjección,  **¡Hola!**, **¡hola!** cuando no queremos decir nada más. Esta segunda opción, es sin duda, la más correcta.

Ejemplos

- **¡Hola!**
- **¡hola!**
- **¡Hola**! Cuanto tiempo sin verte...
- **hola**, cuanto tiempo sin verte...

Comment: A esta altura ya casi nadie usa el signo de apertura en chat